# Online styles and themes resource for my Android application?

Tags: android, themes, android-styles, android-theme

As a coder, and not being a designer, I was wondering if there is any community site that provides simple themes or styles for Android applications.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michael, you may be interested to have a look at [GreenDroid](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid#readme), whilst the themeing may be slightly basic, it will give you a clean and consistent style across your application.

[image]

The [developer](http://www.cyrilmottier.com/) behind the project, gave a pretty good demonstration on it at this years [DroidCon](http://uk.droidcon.com/) and I was very impressed.

If you have an android phone, search for "GDCatalog" and try out the demos

You can also watch the aforementioned droidcon talk [here](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/os-mobile-server/smooth-ui)